# gdb not break while set watch

Tags: debugging, gdb, watchpoint

I debug a process with GDB and set `watch` to break when value in address changed, but it doesn't work!

Here is the initial value:

```
(gdb) x/s 0x60c010
0x60c010:       "aaaaa"
```

Set a watch break point

```
(gdb) watch *0x60c010
Hardware watchpoint 2: *0x60c010
(gdb) commands
Type commands for breakpoint(s) 2, one per line.
End with a line saying just "end".
>echo "changed!!!!"
>end
```

Check the watch:

```
(gdb) info breakpoints
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
2       hw watchpoint  keep y                      *0x60c010
        echo "changed!!!!"
```

Change the value

```
(gdb) p (void*)memset(0x60c010,'c',5)
$2 = (void *) 0x60c010
```

Check if value changed

```
(gdb) x/s 0x60c010
0x60c010:       "ccccc"
```

The problem that the breakpoint didn't stop the process even I change the value into that address

Comment: A watchpoint is hit when the target program changes the value at the address, not when you manually edit with gdb.

Comment: I have to look at it some more, but there is a pair of suspiciously-named functions  `disable_watchpoints_before_interactive_call_start` and `enable_watchpoints_after_interactive_call_stop`.